# Variable cfform values - nested pound sign

Tags: variables, loops, coldfusion, nested

I am having trouble with a problem. I am using cfoutput to run the results of a query inside a form. There are a few cfselects that are dynamically named, i.e. entry_1, entry_2, etc. These are then passed to an actionpage alonge with the record count in the url, where I want to insert them into a database with a cfloop.

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#url.Count#" index="i">  
<cfquery name="id_#i#" datasource="xxx">Insert Into table1(entry_level) Values(#form.entry_#i##)</cfquery>  
</cfloop>
```

And it's tossing an error everytime. I've tried using array format, but I still can't get it to work. Please help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't construct a dynamic struct selector that way.  You can do something like the following to get the same result.

So, using the following data:

```
<cfset url.count = 3>
<cfset form.entry_1 = 1>
<cfset form.entry_2 = 2>
<cfset form.entry_3 = 3>
```

Something like this would work -

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#url.Count#" index="i">  
  <cfquery name="id_#i#" datasource="xxx">
    Insert Into table1(entry_level) Values(#form['entry_' & i]#)
  </cfquery>  
</cfloop>
```

ColdFusion basically gives you two ways to access a value of a structure, either via a . notation or via brackets.  If you are trying to access a structure via a dynamic key, you have to use brackets.

By the way, slightly better would be:

```
   <cfloop from="1" to="#url.Count#" index="i">  
      <cfquery name="id_#i#" datasource="xxx">
        Insert Into table1(entry_level) Values(<cfqueryparam value="#form['entry_' & i]#">)
      </cfquery>  
    </cfloop>
```

cfQueryParam automatically escapes the entry so that you don't have to worry about SQL injection attacks.  It can also make the query slightly more efficient.

Comment: Wow, this is a huge help! Thanks so much! (sorry for the newbie question)

Comment: You have no idea how many times I've tripped up on this one, and I've been doing CF for 15 years.

Comment: Do not forget to add the correct `cfsqltype` to the cfqueryparam. If omitted, CF defaults to `cf_sql_char` which forces an implicit conversion for dates and numbers (sometimes leading to unexpected results).